# Python - Iterate through two csvs to extract an average

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two large csv files. "A" contains elements and their associated nodes, N1-N4

> Elem,N1,N2,N3,N4

"B" contains Nodes and their associated x,y,z locations.

> Node,xLoc,yLoc,zLoc

I have been trying to think of the structure of a list comprehension that would iterate through the elements in "A", and average the x,y,z coordinates for each associated node, N1,N2,N3,N4. Ultimately I would like to return an array of elements and an averaged location.

Any hints on where to start?

Comment: Can you use `pandas` library?

Comment: You could use `pandas` and provide some example data.

Comment: @roganjosh if pandas would have been tagged then yes otherwise there is no point in installing a new library when we have `csv` module :P

Comment: You could start by providing sample data and an expected output, and heck, maybe even some code you have tried!

Comment: Why don't you compile the node list with associated coordinates into a dictionary first? Then you just loop through the elements in A  and compile the needed averages.